# Same code different results from Py2.7 to Py3.4. Where is the mistake?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I am refactoring a few lines of code found in Harrington, P. (2012). Machine Learning in Action, Chapters 11 and 12. The code is supposed to build an FP-tree from a test dataset and it goes as it follows.

```
from __future__ import division, print_function

class treeNode:
    '''
    Basic data structure for an FP-tree (Frequent-Pattern).
    '''

    def __init__(self, nameValue, numOccur, parentNode):
        self.name = nameValue
        self.count = numOccur
        self.nodeLink = None
        self.parent = parentNode
        self.children = {}

    def inc(self, numOccur):
        '''
        Increments the count variable by a given amount.
        '''
        self.count += numOccur

    def disp(self, ind=1):
        '''
        Displays the tree in text.
        '''
        print('{}{}:{}'.format('-'*(ind-1),self.name,self.count))
        for child in list(self.children.values()):
            child.disp(ind+1)


def createTree(dataSet, minSup=1):
    '''
    Takes the dataset and the minimum support
    and builds the FP-tree. 
    '''
    headerTable = {} #stores the counts

    #loop over the dataset and count the frequency of each term.
    for trans in dataSet:
        for item in trans:
            headerTable[item] = headerTable.get(item, 0) + dataSet[trans]

    #scan the header table and delete items occurring less than minSup
    for k in list(headerTable.keys()):
        if headerTable[k] < minSup:
            del(headerTable[k])
    freqItemSet = set(headerTable.keys())

    #if no item is frequent, quit
    if len(freqItemSet) == 0:
        return None, None

    #expand the header table
    #so it can hold a count and pointer to the first item of each type.
    for k in list(headerTable.keys()):
        headerTable[k] = [headerTable[k], None]

    #create the base node, which contains the 'Null Set'
    retTree = treeNode('Null Set', 1, None)

    #iterate over the dataset again
    #this time using only items that are frequent
    for tranSet, count in list(dataSet.items()):
        localD = {}
        for item in tranSet:
            if item in freqItemSet:
                localD[item] = headerTable[item][0]

        if len(localD) > 0:
            #sort the items and the call updateTree()
            orderedItems = [v[0] for v in sorted(list(localD.items()),
                            key=lambda p: p[1], reverse=True)]
            updateTree(orderedItems, retTree, headerTable, count)

    return retTree, headerTable


def updateTree(items, inTree, headerTable, count):
    if items[0] in inTree.children:
        inTree.children[items[0]].inc(count)
    else:
        #Populate tree with ordered freq itemset
        inTree.children[items[0]] = treeNode(items[0], count, inTree)
        if headerTable[items[0]][1] == None:
            headerTable[items[0]][1] = inTree.children[items[0]]
        else:
            updateHeader(headerTable[items[0]][1],inTree.children[items[0]])

    #Recursively call updateTree on the remaining items
    if len(items) > 1:
        updateTree(items[1::], inTree.children[items[0]], headerTable, count)


def updateHeader(nodeToTest, targetNode):
    while (nodeToTest.nodeLink != None):
        nodeToTest = nodeToTest.nodeLink
    nodeToTest.nodeLink = targetNode


def loadSimpDat():
    simpDat = [['r', 'z', 'h', 'j', 'p'],
               ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w', 'v', 'u', 't', 's'],
               ['z'],
               ['r', 'x', 'n', 'o', 's'],
               ['y', 'r', 'x', 'z', 'q', 't', 'p'],
               ['y', 'z', 'x', 'e', 'q', 's', 't', 'm']]
    return simpDat


def createInitSet(dataSet):
    retDict = {}
    for trans in dataSet:
        retDict[frozenset(trans)] = 1
    return retDict

simpDat = loadSimpDat()
initSet = createInitSet(simpDat)
myFPtree, myHeaderTab = createTree(initSet, 3)
myFPtree.disp()
```

This code run without errors in both Python 2.7.9 and 3.4.3. However the output I get is different. Moreover, the output I get with using Py2.7 is consistent while running the same code over and over again with Py3.4 leads to different results.

The correct result is the one obtained using Py2.7 but I cannot figure out why it doesn't work on 3.4.

Why?
What is wrong with this code when interpreted with Python3?

The output describe a defined tree. The order of the branches can change, but the underlined tree shall be the same. This is always the case with Python2 where the output looks like this:

```
-x:1
--s:1
---r:1
-z:5
--x:3
---y:3
----s:2
-----t:2
----r:1
-----t:1
--r:1
```

It should represent this tree.

```
    Null
   /    \  
  x      z
 / \    / \
s   r  x   r
|      |
r      y
      / \
     s   r
     |   |
     t   t
```

This is an example of the wrong result I get using Python3.

```
-z:5
--r:1
--x:3
---t:3
----y:2
-----s:2
----r:1
-----y:1
-x:1
--r:1
---s:1
```

P.S. I have tried to use OrderedDict instead of {}, it doesn't change anything...

Comment: `del` is not a function.

Comment: you are right, but it doesn't change anything...

Answer (score 0):

What seem to happen is that you rely on the ordering of `dict` iteration (ie the order of `d.keys()`, `d.items()` etc). While both python2 and python3 guarantee that the iteration order is consistent during the execution it doesn't guarantee that it is consistent from run to run.

Therefore it's a correct behaviour that the order of the output differs from run to run. That you get the same result from run to run in python2 is pure "luck".

You can get python3 to behave deterministic by setting the `PYTHONHASHSEED` environment variable to a fixed value, but probably you shouldn't rely on `dict` iteration to be deterministic.

Comment: [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) is dict subclass with deterministic order of iteration.

Comment: the line `orderedItems = [v[0] for v in sorted(list(localD.items()), key=lambda p: p[1], reverse=True)]` is taking care of keeping the tree in order..

Comment: @skyking I have thought about that, but it doesn't seem to be the cause of the behaviour I am experiencing here. Running the code with Python2, on different terminals dozens of times give always the same answer... Have you tried to run the code? Do you get different answers with Python2?

Comment: @alec_djinn The lack of guarantee is not a guarantee that you will not observe that what's not guaranteed. Python2 does not guarantee that it will give the same answer, it just happens to be that it does. That's what I meant by "luck" - that the implementation of python2 behaves this way. This is an example why it's a bad idea to rely on a behaviour that is not guaranteed by documentation/specification - the behaviour may simply change.

Comment: @alec_djinn. You are sorting your items, but then you simply iterate through that ordered list in `updateTree`. One of the above suggested methods of preserving order in a Dict would look to be your best bet.

Comment: @SiHa I have tried to use OrderedDict, it doesn't change! And again, I got the correct result using Py2 but not using Py3...

Comment: @alec_djinn You will have to explain what is the "correct" result, and why. To me it looks just like you have an arbitrary order of the branches in Py2 as well, but for some reason it's considered to be the correct one. What `OrderedDict` does is to make for a specified iteration order, but that may not be the order you have in mind.

Comment: @skyking I am following the example reported in chapter 12 of [this book](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjwzvLA9KvJAhVG6w4KHf0sAngQFgghMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww2.ift.ulaval.ca%2F~chaib%2FIFT-4102-7025%2Fpublic_html%2FFichiers%2FMachine_Learning_in_Action.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFtPqFF8Znuabql6wV7Pa4PCwUg9g&sig2=SOhRfxGXJkh1V-86ElbD2g) the **correct** result is the one reported there and I get the very same result using the above code on Py2.

Comment: @skyking Also, even if the order of the branches changes, the branches are correct in Py2 but not in Py3. For example `Null-x-s-r` is correct, but `Null-x-r-s` is not. If I have the x branch before or after the z branch, that  it doesn't matter, but the order of the nodes in each sub-branch it does.

Comment: @alec_djinn I haven't read that book, but I assume you have. Have they motivated that this is **the** correct answer? That is that this is the only correct way to order the branches? If that's so then they would probably describe which order the branches should be ordered. However I suspect that the ordering is not significant (partly because they doesn't seem to make much effort to ensure ordering) and the result shown is just the result that happens to be produced by python2.

Comment: @skyking I understand your point, it just make me crazy that running that on Py2 leads over and over to the same result but not on Py3... I'll contact the author if nothing else come up here... Thank you for your time anyway.